# Wordpress blog theme customization

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a personal website with Photofocus theme (https://catchthemes.com/themes/photofocus-pro). I completed the website design, now designing a blog page. Actually, I need a custom theme for my blogs ie 4 column thumbnail design. Please see the design below.

Design website link: https://blog.bitdiscovery.com/
[image]

But Photofocus blog theme looks different(See image attached)

[image]

Following are my doubts?

- How to customize the Photofocus blog theme to meet my requirement?
- Do I need to manually edit PHP files to achieve the design?
- Can I purchase a different theme for the blog only(ie my desired design is
  also a WordPress site - https://blog.bitdiscovery.com/)
- Suggest me the ideal solution?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- From the [Theme Instructions](https://catchthemes.com/themes/photofocus-pro)

`You can customize this theme using cool additional features through Customizer at "Appearance => Customize" from your WordPress Dashboard.`

- If needed, you could contact them as mentioned on [this page](https://catchthemes.com/hire-customizer/) to customize it for you.
- It should be possible to use another theme for your blog when 1) The site is on a subdomain (and thus a separate WordPress installation) or 2) when the theme provides a "blog" template option (but that would be only partially different).
- If you are looking for a flexible, totally customizable solution, I can recommend [Oxygen Builder](https://oxygenbuilder.com/). But you'll need some knowledge about HTML/CSS/PHP for it.

Comment: @Thanks for your reply. I will check above links